# ES6 WeakMap Class encapsulation

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand why I need to use WeakMaps to create private class members, instead of just using a normal variable. They both create encapsulation with closures, and module imports.

```
(function encapsulation() {
  const my_var = 'My secret info';
  const my_var2 = new WeakMap();

  class Test {
    constructor() {
      my_var2.set(this, 'My secret info 2');
      console.log(my_var); // My secret info
      console.log(my_var2.get(this)); // My secret info 2
    }
  }

  const t = new Test();
})();


console.log(my_var); // undefined
console.log(my_var2); // undefined

// Same result!
```

Comment: You've only got one instance of `Test` though

Comment: I want the privacy of WeakMaps so that people using my code can't access class members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with an ordinary variable like `my_var` is that it will only save data for a single instantiation of the class:

```js
const Test = (function encapsulation() {
  let my_var = 'My secret info';

  class Test {
    constructor(param) {
      my_var = param;
    }
    getInfo() {
      return my_var;
    }
  }
  return Test;
})();

const t1 = new Test('foo');
const t2 = new Test('bar');
console.log(t1.getInfo());
// the above returns 'bar'... uh oh, but we passed in 'foo' to `t1`! Our data is lost!
console.log(t2.getInfo()); // 'bar'
```

Thus, the need for a `WeakMap`, to hold separate data for *each instantiation*:

```js
const Test = (function encapsulation() {
  const my_var2 = new WeakMap();

  class Test {
    constructor(param) {
      my_var2.set(this, param);
    }
    getInfo() {
      return my_var2.get(this);
    }
  }
  return Test;
})();

const t1 = new Test('foo');
const t2 = new Test('bar');
console.log(t1.getInfo()); // 'foo', as expected
console.log(t2.getInfo()); // 'bar', as expected
```

Comment: That makes sense for proper encapsulation. So if i were using methods and properties that weren't mutated, going with a constant would be fine?

Comment: I'm not sure what mutation has to do with it - the problem is being able to access the data afterwards. Mutation is separate from reassignment.

Comment: Ah sorry, I suppose I meant to say if I only had one instance of the class ever. Having a constant would make sense then, as it wouldn't be re-asigned

Comment: You mean as one of the `my_var`s? Sure, but you wouldn't be able to pass private data *into* it, it would have to be hard-coded.